# Identify this circuit symbol with two overlapping circles

Tags: components, component-selection, electrical

[image]

I came across some images of schematics and have never seen this component before - what is it?

Comment: Probably a current source.

Comment: This is a current mirror. The answer is here: [https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/373569/where-does-this-current-source-symbol-come-from](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/373569/where-does-this-current-source-symbol-come-from)

Comment: In fairness to the OP, it's hard to research something when you only have an image (symbol, in this case) and don't know what to search for, because you don't know what it is.

Comment: Maybe, but I could argue that the fact that you are explaining Google's image search to me, suggests that you think I don't already know about it. In which case, perhaps the OP didn't either? Secondly, I tried it and found a description of the symbol on the [4th hit](https://www.norwegiancreations.com/2018/05/electronics-101-pt-4-rl-and-rc-circuits/). However, their description disagrees with your answer. So which is correct? You answer is; but had the OP simply done an image search, s/he might have arrived at an inaccurate result.

Comment: @mguima: How can that be a current mirror if it has only two terminals? As far as I know a current mirror would require four terminals.